# How do I concat a column's unique values in a group by for MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I know how to concat all the values for a field in a group by (see below), but I don't want repeated values. For example, if "Bob" did 5 actions of type "1" and also a type "2", I want only: `1,2`, not `1,1,1,1,1,2`.

However, the UNIQUE must *not* be on the total query because I still need the values of the other columns for those actions.

```
SELECT
  user.name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(type SEPARATOR ',') AS types,
  SUM(produced)
FROM user
GROUP BY user.name;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use distinct inside group_cocat function

```
SELECT
  user.name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(distinct type SEPARATOR ',') AS types,
  SUM(produced)
FROM user
GROUP BY user.name;
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.... do the first level of aggregation in a sub-query then do the concatenation on top of it.

```
SELECT TMP.NAME
    , GROUP_CONCAT(TYPE SEPARATOR ',') AS TYPES
    , SUM(PRODUCED)
FROM (
    SELECT USER.NAME
        , TYPE
        , SUM(PRODUCED) PRODUCED
    FROM USER
    GROUP BY USER.NAME
        , TYPE
) TMP
GROUP BY TMP.NAME;
```